# How to send many/multiple post requests of JSONObjects on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, post

There's a lot of questions on StackOverflow for sending a single POST request on Android, but none of them cover cases where you're receiving lots of data from a sensor connected to your phone and need to Post Request that data as you receive it.

I'm receiving data from a sensor connected to my Android, and need to to send it to a Flask server hosted on Heroku.

```
public void sendToFlask(JSONObject jsonParam) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("URLHERE");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

This code unfortunately errors out for creating `too many files`

I understand that the solution here may be to use a global `HttpURLConnection` but unfortunately that also gives me the error of `java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after response has been read` This happens after I move the `conn` and `url` variables to global scope and set them in `onCreate`

Comment: Use `Retrofit` networking library it will be super easy for you to handle networking.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Any chance you could post an example of how this could help to post many JSONObjects to a Flask server?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun A lot of the examples I've found still cover only sending single Post requests, I'm not sure how to do it for multiple asynchronous requests

Comment: Add all json object to jsonarray and send it.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya There isn't a set number of JSONObjects, I'm receiving data from a sensor that never stops being received (ideally) and I need to be uploading that data to my Flask server. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: you need to apply some mechanism for that. like, share data periodically after some seconds.